# Setting the typeof value from combobox Items in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am new to C# and I am making a simple table by coding not connecting to an external database. I have a Combobox (Dropdown List) so that the user can select the data type of the Column from dropdown list items and then that selected Item is set as the data type of the Column. I need the selected item in this line :

```
            customer.Columns.Add(cn , typeof(long));
```

and this is my whole class :

```
 namespace HomeWork1
 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public String tn;
    public String cn;
    DataTable customer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Boolean");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Byte");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Char");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("DateTime");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Decimal");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Double");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Int16");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Int32");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Int64");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("String");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tn = txtTableName.Text;

        customer = new DataTable(tn);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn = txtColumnName.Text;
        customer.Columns.Add(cn , typeof(long));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = customer;
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: typeof(long) or typeof(cn)?

Comment: @UthistranS. cn is just a String where contains the column name that gets it from a TextBox , I want the selected value to be in place of typeof(long) but I recieve error

Comment: We don't see you error. What is the error message saying?

Comment: See Type.Parse() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397503.aspx

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes This code is right , I want to replace the typeof value from ComboBox selected Item , Like This : `            customer.Columns.Add(cn , typeof(combobox1.SelectedItem));
`

Comment: Yes, and what is the problem? What does not work?  If you get an error message, tell us this error message. Is it a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes see when I put this line : `customer.Columns.Add(cn , typeof(combobox1.SelectedItem));` it gives this error and I can't compile , error  `Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'combobox1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It is still giving the same error even I changed b to upper case

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The problem is that typeof() method doesn't accept a value like this : `typeof(comboBox1.SelectedItem)`

Comment: Ok, but now you are getting a different error message. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. `combobox1` and `comboBox1` are not the same. Since your combo box is named `comboBox1` with an upper case "B", write it like this:

```
customer.Columns.Add(cn ,
    Type.GetType("System." + (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem));
'                                         ^ upper case "B"
```

You can have two variables which differ only in upper / lower case:

```
int x = 1;
int X = 100;
```

These are really two different variables!

---

Note: there are different ways of getting a `Type` object:

1. From a type name given as identifier

   ```
    Type t = typeof(int); // typeof(int) is known at compile time.
   ```
2. From an object

   ```
    Type t = someObject.GetType(); // Known only at runtime.
   ```
3. From a type name given as string

   ```
    string s = "System.Int32";
    Type t = Type.GetType(s);
   ```

Note: `GetType()` is a method all types inherit from [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Since you have type name strings in your combo box, use the third version.

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System." + (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
customer.Columns.Add(cn , t);
```

Or directly add `Type` objects to your combo box instead of strings:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(typeof(bool));
comboBox1.Items.Add(typeof(byte));
```

Then simply get the type with

```
Type t = (Type)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
customer.Columns.Add(cn , t);
```